# How to access values of a list within a linked list?

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a linked list which stores objects of a class which has 4 data members,2strings,one integer and a List of objects of another class.

How do I access the values of the list within the linked list?

Ok this is what i have

LogProcess lp=new LogProcess(revision,author,date,pathinfo,msg);

pathinfo is a list of the format List.revision,author,date,msg are strings.

Now PathInfo is a class having three data members action,kind,pathinfo.All 3 are strings.

Now let us say if I am passing a linked List to a constructor and want to access the values of action,kind and pathinfo,what do I do?

Comment: I think that a quick query (like "java linkedlist tutorial") will answer your question.

Comment: This question is not interesting since it can ben answer very quickly with a google search.

Comment: Please post some code to support your description. Also, check out the Java tutorials for using the standard Collections.

Comment: Everyone relax and help him rewrite the question instead of downvoting. @coder - It's not clear where you're stuck

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using `LinkedList` you would call `get`.  If you aren't using generics (`LinkedList<YourFooObject> YourLinkedList;` would be using them, `LinkedList YourLinkedList` would not), then you would need a cast, like this

```
 YourFooObject foo = (YourFooObject)YourLinkedList.get(0)
```

Comment: I don't recommend this because that is assuming that the item in index 0 is a "YourFooObject", you need a "instanceof" to verify its type. I posted my answer below.

Comment: @coder - This isn't Burger King.  Your question is poorly written, if you want a good answer, ask a good question.  See e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
//Retriver one of the nodes of the linked list
YourObjectType node = yourLinkedList.get(int index)

//access the list instance variable of your object (depending on it visibility)
node.myList; //if accessible from here
MyList myList = node.getMyList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `get(index)` function of the LinkedList will return the element at the desired index.

```
YourStructure data = list.get(someindex);
```

Now you can get the list from your single object:

```
LinkedList<Something> sublist = data.getList();
```

Then you can iterate through that sublist like normal: with a `for` loop, a `foreach`, or an `iterator`.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best way to go about this is like with a foreach loop of an Object array/list/collection such:

```
for(Object o : list) {
     if(o instanceof String) {
        //Object in list is a string
        String s = (String)o; //make sure to properly cast the object now that you know it is of proper type
     }
     else if(o instanceof int) {
        //object in list is an int
     }
     else if(o instanceof classA) {
        //object in list is from classA and you get the idea
     }
     else if(o instanceof classB) {
     }
//etc..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an iterator for your `LinkedList` to access the object of your `LinkedList` which is your specific `class object`, something like this would work:

```
LinkedList<YourObject> list = new LinkedList<YourObject>();
ListIterator listIt = list.listIterator();
YourObject sample = listIt.next();//or any of the objects you need in your list
int valueOfSample = sample.getFirstParameter();//Assuming getFirstParameter is a method of your object class that returns the first integer parameter
```